# How to make tableview like Calendar app's detail view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I think UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle will be close to Calendar App's detail view, but I don't know how to make it. or does any solution for this tableview cell?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing just a `Grouped table` view with dynamic height `cells`. You can create a `grouped table` view and calculate `height` of `cell in` `heightForRowAtIndexPath` by using `CGSize` and create `reuable cell` with two `labels`.